# Problemas con el http localhost

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, web, http

estoy intentado abrir un localhost ejecutando en nodeJS, pero la página carga indefinidamente sin mostrar resultado.

```
const http= require(`http`)
http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.write(`Hello World`)
    response.end
}).listen(5000)
console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto 5000`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un servidor en node te recomiendo usar express de esta forma muy sencilla:

```
const express = require("express");
//Creas la instancia
const app = express();
//Si quieres parsear los datos a JSON
app.use(express.json());
app.use((req, res) => {
return res.send("Hola que tal!);
});
app.listen(5000, () => {console.log('Servidor funcionando en http://localhost:5000});
```

Comment: Gracias, ya pude arreglar me falto cerrar el 'response.end' con paréntesis

Comment: @Alex, si resolviste tu problema sin utilizar esta la respuesta, no la marques como aceptada. Puedes escribir tu propia respuesta y marcar esa como aceptada. Un saludo.